# I downloaded a flutter project from internet but i got this error: "null. The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory."

Tags: flutter, dart

I installed a project from internet but when i am trying to build that application, i am getting this error: "Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user."

can anyone help me ?
my flutter version is: 2.2.2

Comment: can you add path of  your flutter SDK and project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.